# How can we find coefficient of variation for each unique ID in a data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

So, I tried a couple ideas about finding coefficient of variation, per ID, but nothing has worked out so far.  I thought I could add it to my existing dataframe, like this.

```
df['CV_Exp'] = df.groupby(['IDName'])[['Expense']].std() / df.groupby(['IDName'])[['Expense']].mean()
```

That runs, but the result is all NANs.

If I try to add the results to a new data frame, like this.

```
df_new['CV_Exp'] = df.groupby(['Location'])[['Expense']].std() / df.groupby(['Location'])[['Expense']].mean()
```

I get an error message saying: `NameError: name 'df_new' is not defined`

Here is some sample data that I am using.

```
import pandas as pd
  
# initialize list of lists
data = [[110,2020,'CHASE CENTER',53901,8904,44997], 
        [110,2019,'CHASE CENTER',57999,4921,53078], 
        [110,2018,'CHASE CENTER',91015,9945,81070], 
        [640,2020,'LAMBEAU WI',76214,5773,70441], 
        [619,2020,'SAL AIRPORT',93000,8278,84722]]

# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Location', 'Year', 'Location_Description', 'Revenue', 'Expense', 'Profit_Or_Loss'])


df['CV_Exp'] = df.groupby(['Location'])[['Expense']].std() / df.groupby(['Location'])[['Expense']].mean()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a [mre] ?

Comment: use solution1 of my answer. ID 110 will have values. There will still be nan values for the other however, because in your test data location 640 and 619 have only 1 value, you can't get a std of a single value. You might need to consider a .fillna() afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try one of the following two solutions:

**1: groupby with transform**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(102)
df = pd.DataFrame({'IDName': 1*(np.random.randn(10)>1), 'Expense': 10+2*np.random.randn(10)})

df['CV_Exp'] = df.groupby(['IDName'])[['Expense']].transform('std') / df.groupby(['IDName'])[['Expense']].transform('mean')

#    IDName    Expense    CV_Exp
# 0       1  11.946330  0.173619
# 1       0   9.951630  0.173619
# 2       1   9.030144  0.173619
# 3       0   7.781471  0.191531
# 4       1   8.882050  0.191531
# 5       0  12.084773  0.191531
# 6       0   6.575475  0.191531
# 7       0  10.272240  0.191531
# 8       0   9.071112  0.191531
# 9       0  10.101960  0.191531
```

**2: groupby with merge**

```
np.random.seed(102)
df = pd.DataFrame({'IDName': 1*(np.random.randn(10)>1), 'Expense': 10+2*np.random.randn(10)})

df_grouped = df.groupby(['IDName'])[['Expense']].std() / df.groupby(['IDName'])[['Expense']].mean()
df['CV_Exp'] = df.merge(df_grouped.reset_index(), on=['IDName'])['Expense_y']

#    IDName    Expense    CV_Exp
# 0       1  11.946330  0.173619
# 1       0   9.951630  0.173619
# 2       1   9.030144  0.173619
# 3       0   7.781471  0.191531
# 4       1   8.882050  0.191531
# 5       0  12.084773  0.191531
# 6       0   6.575475  0.191531
# 7       0  10.272240  0.191531
# 8       0   9.071112  0.191531
# 9       0  10.101960  0.191531
```

Comment: Yeah, your solution works. I think the way I was trying to do it was the old way. Thanks so much!!!